# Giant size close button on Window Edge

Tags: windows-7

for some reason I have two applications that have gigantic 'close' buttons that prevent me from using them properly.[image]

Running the appilcations on Windows 7 64 bit.

What might be causing this, and how can I get these to be scaled like normal buttons?

Comment: Let's isolate the problem first. Try creating another user account, logging on with that account and open these problematic apps there. See if you can reproduce the problem. Also, do you mind telling us the names of these mysterious apps?

Comment: Ok, ill try and create another user account and log in with that. About the apps; These apps are so obscure you wouldn't know them. They are from Japan.

Comment: ok that fixed it, but what to do now?

Comment: Now that you've done that, we know that the problem is from your user account settings and not from other stuff. Now, go back to your original user account and try changing your theme by right-clicking on Desktop, selecting "Personalize..." and choosing a new theme.

Comment: ok that worked. ty

Comment: I am happy that it worked. Now let's save this solution for the future generation. I will post it as an official answer. Please click on the gray checkmark besides the answer to make it green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is most likely caused by your user account's display setting.

Right-click on your Desktop and select "Personalize...". Then select a new theme. Doing this restores some of the original settings.